# PHP memory error with Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I am attempting to load a page in a script I am writing. This script draws a fairly large form. PHP returns the following.

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 11272192) (tried to allocate 1300805 bytes) in /home/****/public_html/admin/templates_c/9640f8a7d8b0c5b7c7bd2706a88dd0074b04697b.file.template2.tpl.php on line 51
```

Memory limit on this server is currently set to 1012 MB. I am unable to locate any troublesome loops that could be leaking memory and I am not certain how to locate the problem.

Comment: your limit override isn't working then, 11272192 -> ~10.75 megs. If 1012 meg was actually working, then it'd say `1061158912` instead.

Comment: Any suggestions what I should look at?

Comment: phpinfo(), see what .ini files are being loaded. then start tracing through the .ini file chain (main php.ini, per-dir user.ini, httpd.conf/.htaccess php_value overrides, ini_set(), etc...) and see if/where your override is getting overriden, or outright ignored.